# mpirun was unable to launch the specified application as it could not access or execute an executable in R

Tags: r, package, mpi, openmpi, niagara-4

I am trying to run irace on Compute Canada, and when I used *openmpi* module, it always gave me this error message below:

> mpirun was unable to launch the specified application as it could not access or execute an executable:
>
> Executable: /scratch/irace/test.R
>
> Node: niaXXXX
>
> while attempting to start process rank 0.

My bash script is written

```
#!/bin/sh
#SBATCH --nodes=5
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=40
#SBATCH --mem=0
#SBATCH --mail-type=ALL
#SBATCH --output=/scratch/irace/irace-%j.out
#SBATCH --error=/scratch/irace/irace-%j.err

module load NiaEnv/2019b
module load gcc
module load r
module load openmpi

cd /scratch/irace
mpirun -np 5 /scratch/irace/test.R --parallel 4
```

When I submitted this job script, the run failed. However, when I replaced the last statement

```
mpirun -np 5 /scratch/irace/test.R --parallel 4
```

with the statement

```
Rscript ./test.R
```

, it would run all good and give me the results. What are the causes of this and how can I fix this bug and get it run on Compute Canada?

Comment: Is `/scratch/irace/test.R` on a shared filesystem accessible by **all** the compute nodes? if you have any doubts, you'd rather ask your sysadmin/helpdesk.

Comment: How can I see if the test.R is on a shared filesystem? I transfer it from the local machine to the Linux environment. If it's not on a shared filesystem, should I contact the admin working at Compute Canada? Thanks!

Comment: you can `df /scratch/irace/test.R`, both on your frontend and job script, then compare the outputs. If you cannot find this information in the doc, then yes, ask sysadmin/helpdesk how to use the shared filesystem for MPI jobs.

Answer (score 0):

Consider

```
cd /scratch/irace
mpirun -np 5 Rscript test.R --parallel 4
```

`mpirun` expects an executable (`Rscript`) rather than an R script (your `test.R`).

That is also why `Rscript test.R` worked fine because `Rscript` is an executable that interprets your `test.R` R script. But depending on your R script, this probably used only one of your 5 requested nodes.

Consider using the `pbdMPI` package for simplification of your R code and use of all requested nodes for computation (SPMD style) rather than a manager-workers style that leaves the manager idle much of the time.